# Make SSH not use VPN

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, vpn, sshfs

I recently started using a VPN server on my laptop. Everything now routes through it, including my SSHFS mounts and SSH shell to/from my FTP server. Because of that, it is now very slow and unresponsive.

Is it possible to still use the VPN "globally" with the exception of all SSH related tasks? (Only the laptop uses the VPN connection, not the FTP server)

Arch Linux.

Comment: This is becoming an issue for me with working from home along with every other employee during COVID19!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `BindAddress` option, which will allow you to not to go through the VPN network, even if it is set as a default one.

It can be set in configuration file `~/.ssh/config` as

```
Host your-non-vpn-host
  BindAddress your-local-ip-non-vpn
```

Or just ad-hoc on commandline using `-oBindAddress=your-local-ip-non-vpn` switch to SSH/SFTP/SSHFS.

And how to find your `your-local-ip-non-vpn`? List your local IP addresses using `ip address show` and select the one that is showed next to your "normal" network interface (not the one next to your VPN interface).

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is for sshfs?

Comment: Yes. It should work also for `sshfs`.

Comment: Sorry. Add the configuration file. The inline version using `-o` should be accepted also by `sshfs`.

Comment: So 'your-non-vpn-host' is the server's WAN address, and 'your-local-ip-non-vpn' is my local network IP?

Comment: Yes. The first can be also the hostname or whatever address/name are you using in your commands.

Comment: How do I find out `your-local-ip-non-vpn` while you are connected to VPN? With so much `ifconfig` output my head is spinning. (and it seems that 127.0.0.1 won't work).

Comment: @SridharSarnobat `ifconfig` will list you network interfaces. It depends if you are connected through ethernet or wifi. In the first case, the interface will be something like `eth0`, for wifi something like `wlan0`.

Comment: I'm still not sure if those ip addresses will be the ones to use in the above command since I'd be connected to vpn. But thanks for the reply. Maybe I just don't understand the basics of vpn to even phrase the question correctly